# CRM 2013 JavaScript Form Reload on attribute onChange crashes on IE9/10/11 but works on Firefox & Chrome

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I am having an issue to reload the Form after a field Onchange is triggered. The issue happens only with Internet Explorer.When I change the compatibility mode  with developer tools to 8 It works but 9/10/11 it crashes.

Things I have tried.

- xrm.utility.openentityform.
- window.location.reload
- window.location = document.url

  ```
  function SaveAndRefresh() {
      var id = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
       Xrm.Page.data.save();
        Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("incident", id);
  ```

  }

Any help will be appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: Would you paste the onchange code?

Comment: What issue is happening ? What's the codee ?

Comment: function SaveAndRefresh() {
 var id = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
 Xrm.Page.data.save();
 Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("incident", id);
}

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
Xrm.Page.data.refresh();
```

You'd still call save, so you're code would look like:

```
function SaveAndRefresh() {
   Xrm.Page.data.save();
   Xrm.Page.data.refresh();
}
```

Well, according to the SDK, you could do:

```
Xrm.Page.data.save().then(
    function () {
        alert('Save worked, refresh');
        Xrm.Page.data.refresh();
    },
    function () {
        alert('Save failed!');
    }
);
```

Comment: I have tried that and it works but it gives a confirm dialogue and this not required, as I have a sync custom work that switch the business process flow based on the select value of pick list.So I need to refresh the page once the Business process flow is updated

Comment: I added another example.  I tested this and it didn't work when changing the name of a record.  It always was successful.  If this doesn't work, then I'd iterate through the required fields and confirm that you can save first.  Or you could use something like $('.ms-crm-ImageStrip-inlineedit_warning:visible').length to see if any warnings are showing (although this example is unsupported)